# How should we handle ChatGPT answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging, policy

A new user has posted a number of answers in breach of the [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1701/35069).

There's no attempt to disguise its use, as each answer ends with:

> Chatgpm

I assume they need flagging but as none of the descriptions really fit this particular scenario would the:

> very low quality

flag be appropriate?

Comment: Update - they've all been deleted by the Mods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Use the ”In need of moderator intervention” flag with AI or ChatGPT in the reason