# Do the recent and upcoming policy changes and subsequent moderators' strike affect how LawSE moderates AI content?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging, policy, artificial-inteligence

**TL;DR** Can we have some clarity<sup>1</sup>, please? i.e. To flag or not to flag AI?

The most recent announcement from LawSE's per-site moderators is our *temporary* policy stating that [ChatGPT is banned](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1701/35069), which is supplemented by [DaleM's guidance](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/35069) to:

> Use the ”In need of moderator intervention” flag with AI or ChatGPT in the reason

Things have moved on, and these now appear to be at odds with the network-wide [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389582/906208) although one user commented that "*This post does not match the guidance given to moderators*" (but I don't know how it differs, but that's by-the-by)

The network's policy changes has prompted the [moderators' strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389811/906208), and the publication of an [open letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/) referencing a:

> near-total prohibition on moderating AI-generated content

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I totally understand if this goes unanswered due to the strike, and I won't labour the point :)</sub>

Comment: similar post on MSO: [Does the policy change for AI-generated content affect users who (want to) flag such content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424910/11107541)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [GPT answers are still not allowed on Law.SE](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

It is still appropriate to note this policy in a comment and to flag them for moderator attention.

We will do our best to enforce this policy.  However, because it is not always obvious or certain that an answer came from GPT (even if one or more GPT-detectors says so) at this point we can't commit to what action any particular moderator will take in response to these flags.

As always, any user with sufficient rep can downvote any answer for any reason, including because they believe that the answer violates this Law.SE policy.

Comment: Are any of the mod team involved in the strike?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim Not according to the signatories to the open letter (linked in my post)