# Is the LawSE response to suspected AI generated posts still in force?

Tags: discussion, flagging, artificial-inteligence

The [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1701/35069) states that:

> Posting GPT answers on Law Stack Exchange is temporarily banned.

And the answer from a Moderator when asked [How should we handle ChatGPT answers?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1718/35069) is to:

> Use the ”In need of moderator intervention” flag with AI or ChatGPT in the reason

Here's the rub. I flagged a now-deleted [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94285/35069) that I suspect to be AI (multiple content detectors indicated it is 100% AI-generated).  My flag was declined, with this reply:

> Declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Apart from that link not being in any way helpful, **should suspected AI-generated posts continue to be flagged in this way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, it’s still in force but posts are not deleted for being *suspected* AI

“Evidence” from AI detectors is not an acceptable reason for flagging posts. They are too inaccurate to be reliable. You might as well flip a coin three times and flag the post if you get two heads.

This unacceptable level of false positives is even more egregious where the post is written by a human with English as a second language. AI posts look stilted but so do posts written by non-fluent writers.

If you *know* it’s AI because, for example, the OP says it is, that’s a sufficient reason to flag it.

All the other reasons that you have for flagging are as applicable to AI posts as they are to human ones. It’s also more likely that an AI post will give cause for those flags.

So, if it’s spam, or rude, or needs improvement, etc. flag it. If it’s wrong or otherwise just bad, vote it down or vote to delete it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, I'll stop flagging 100% AI-generated until told otherwise.

Comment: It's not just false positives, but also false negatives.  I asked Alpaca to write a press release covering an absurd situation, pasted it into ZeroGPT, and got a verdict of "0% AI".

Comment: Now that the new "interim" policy was released to all mods, are you going to be deleting answers that fall under those heuristics?