# How To Deal wIth AI Postings At Law.SE

Tags: discussion, moderation, artificial-inteligence

user @SergZ has a modus operandi of making lots of AI posts with minimal editing in other forums and appears to be doing so in this forum, but, of course, it is hard to tell sometimes.

I deleted one of his badly done AI answers as a mod at Politics.SE

I'm inviting discussion on how mods should respond to this in this forum in cases where the answers aren't patently bad ones.

Comment: for the record: [while their recent answer read like a rant and not AI material](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94153/10334), they plugged the answers into an AI and the reply was very much the apologetic Open-AI style

Comment: Related [MetaSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391584/906208) concerning this user - who is currently serving a network-wide suspension until 23/08/2023.

Answer (score 14):

### Our current policy is that they are banned and repeat offenders are breaking the rules

[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

It doesn't matter if the posts are good, bad, or indifferent: if we decide they are AI-generated, they get deleted.

I'm not saying that our policy doesn't have some problems in implementation (e.g. there are both false positives and false negatives in spotting AI content), but it is at least clear and unambiguous in its objectives.

The historical SE policy has been released publicly - [(Historical) Policy on the use of GPT Generators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391626/historical-policy-on-the-use-of-gpt-generators)

It bans using AI detectors (other than our brains) and prevents us suspending users based on those. It does not prevent us banning AI content based on our own assessment and deleting those posts - which is what we are doing.

Unless and until there is a directive from above or a clear consensus to change the policy here, we just follow it as best we can.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147496/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-how-to-deal-with-ai-postings-at-law-se); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.