# What to do about AI edits that are helpful?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, chatgpt

https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57118

This edit was quite clearly done with ChatGPT (see the last paragraph), but it does improve the post. How should edits like this be handled?

Comment: Can you point me to where it "quite clearly" says it was done by AI, please, to help me identify AI in the future.  When I approved the edit, I assumed that @Rohit Gupta had made the effort to improve it manually. But I (as usual) may be mistaken:)

Comment: @Rick the last paragraph in the edit said this:  "Please remember that this text has been converted to normal case, where the first letter of each sentence and proper nouns are capitalized. If you have any more requests or questions, feel free to ask." Rohit Gupta almost certainly pasted the original text into ChatGPT or another LLM with a prompt like "Convert this text to normal case."

Comment: Ah. I see it now in the final sentence. Th@nks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any improvement is welcome!

Note that [the current policy on GPT](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) prohibits using it to generate *answers*.